# Proof that well-ordering implies choice

Tags: proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

Is the following argument correct to show that if every set $S$ can be well-ordered, then for any disjoint indexed family of non-empty sets $(X_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ there exists a map $f: \{ X_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A \} \to \cup_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$ such that $f(X_{\alpha}) \in X_{\alpha}$?

To show the claim, let $f(X_{\alpha}) = \min X_{\alpha}$. Then $f(X_{\alpha}) \in X_{\alpha}$, that is $f$ is the choice function, which exists because $X_{\alpha}$ has a well-ordering $\leq_{\alpha}$ in which $X_{\alpha}$ has a minimum.

Is this correct?

EDIT: It is assumed that the aforementioned $S$ is also non-empty.

Comment: Wow, it looks like you don't even need well-ordering! Trivially, every nonempty set $X_\alpha$ has a **partial ordering** $\le_\alpha$ in which $X_\alpha$ has a minimum . . .

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what is $S$. Namely you need to first fix a well ordering for $\bigcup X_\alpha$, only then the notion of a minimum makes sense.

Other than that, it's fine.

Comment: Well the hypothesis was that every set $S$ has a property, which would mean $X_{\alpha}$ does as well.

Comment: Yes, which is why there is a well ordering of the union. But your proof doesn't appeal to this explicitly.

Comment: @AJY Can't you do it even more simply **without well ordering**? Every nonempty set $X_\alpha$ has an element $x_\alpha$, so just define $f(X_\alpha)=x_\alpha$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I strongly suspect that the OP is thinking, "for each $X_\alpha$ choose a well-ordering . . ." Other than that, his proof is fine.

Comment: Why would I need a well-order of the union? Why is a well-order of $X_{\alpha}$ not enough to choose an element from $X_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @AJY: Every non singleton has more than one well ordering. Which one do you choose? And how?

Comment: Is that ambiguity enough to make the choice impossible?

Comment: @AJY: Yes. Suppose that in general each set has two elements. Certainly you can prove it can be well ordered without any additional assumption. But it is possible that there is a countable family of sets of size 2, from which you cannot choose an element from each pair.

Comment: Why couldn't I also say that $\cup_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$ has multiple well-orders, so I can't work with it either?

Comment: @AJY: Yes, it also has many well orders, but now you only need to choose one for the remainder of the proof.

Comment: So you're saying that the problem with $X_{\alpha}$ is that I'd just have to choose over the set of well-orders of $X_{\alpha}$, and thereafter I'd be able to take my minima.

Comment: @AJY: Yes, or choose *one* well-order which well-orders *all* the $X_\alpha$'s simultaneously.